# Python: How to remove certain words in a string

Tags: python, string

I have the following string:

> right then the treasure be right on that island right where we left it
>   then when ye left me

My task is to delete everything except the reoccurring words. So the output would be:

`>>>right right then left`

I have managed to get the following output:

`>>>['right', 'then', 'the', 'treasure', 'be', 'on', 'that', 'island', 'where', 'we', 'left', 'it', 'when', 'ye', 'me']`

Now if i manage to delete the above words from the original string, I will be left the the correct output. How do i do this?

Comment: In that sense your output should be:- right right right left left then then. Am i right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
words = Counter('right then the treasure be right on that island right where we left it then when ye left me')
for word, count in words.most_common():
    if count > 1:
        print word,
```

Comment: The desired output is "right right then left" which is unclear wheater should include all the occurance be included or only once.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the desired output, printing a list of all the ocurrences of the words that have a count > 1 in the string

```
your_string = 'right then the treasure be right on that island right where we left it     then when ye left me'
words = your_string.split()
words_that_occur_more_than_once = [word for word in words if words.count(word)>1]
words_that_occur_more_than_once.sort(reverse=True)
print(' '.join(words_that_occur_more_than_once))
```

This will order the string the way you want it. I don't understand why the output should have one less 'right' word in it.

Comment: When I run your code in Python 3.4.1, it gives the following error `print(words_that_occur_more_than_once.join(' '))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'`.

Comment: It should be `' '.join(words_that_occur_more_than_once)`

Comment: This gives me the output: right then right right left then left
The output should be: right right then left

Comment: What are the rules, then? right is three times in the string... you can order it if you want

Answer (score 0):

First create a method to determine if the string shows up more than once.  Then use that method to extract the words you want, and then reprint.

```
# Method returns True if the searchWord is in the text only once.
# Returns False otherwise.
def occursOnlyOnce(searchWord, text):
    count = 0
    words = text.split();
    for word in words:
        if word == searchWord:
            count += 1

    if count == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


# Initial input text.
initialText = "right then the treasure be right on that island right where we left it then when ye left me"

# Split words into a list.
words = initialText.split();

# List of recurring words only.
finalWords = []

# Extract words that don't appear once, and place into a list.
for word in words:
    if not occursOnlyOnce(word, initialText):
        finalWords.append(word)

# Assemble a space-delimited string containing the words.
finalStr = " ".join(finalWords)

# Print out the words that occur more than once.
print(finalStr)
```

Comment: :O Even in assembler we could have less code for such a trivial task

Comment: For beginners, it is easier to understand code that is broken down into smaller logical steps, and is well-commented.

Answer (score 0):

This code will remove everything properly and remove extra spaces.

```
def removePhrase(string, charArray):

    string = str(string)
    text = string.split()

    for x in range (0, len(text)):
        for y in range (0, len(charArray)):
            if text[x] == charArray[y]:
                text[x] = text[x].replace(charArray[y], "")

    text = " ".join(text)
    return text

string = "right then the treasure be right on that island right where we left it then when ye left me"
text = string.split()
charArray = [word for word in text if text.count(word)<2]
print(charArray)
finalString = removePhrase(string, charArray)
finalString = ' '.join(finalString.split())
print(finalString)
```

Comment: Mine returns "right then right right left then left". Yours return "right then left"